# Iterate with index

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, flutter, dart

Is there a way to iterate through a list having access to the object and the index?
For example, I have:

```
Row(
          children: items.map((item) {
            int index = items.indexOf(item);
            return widget(index);
          }).toList()),
```

I would like to have something that gives me directly the item and its index, so that I don't have to evaluate the index with:

```
    int index = items.indexOf(item);
```

but write only:

```
Row(
              children: items.functionThatIWant((index,item) {
                return widget(index);
              }).toList()),
```

Comment: see [enumerate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/quiver.iterables/enumerate.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `_current` as your index, then you can get the item at the desired index by doing

```dart
items.elementAt(_current);
```

That is assuming that `items` is indeed a `List<T>`